# To get data related to the GROUP_CONCAT in MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

### Table 1

[image: Table1]

### Table 2

[image: Table2]

This is the result for Those Two table i got By using this query:

```
SELECT t1.*, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.content_id) 
FROM news_categories t1 
LEFT JOIN news_content t2 
    ON t2.cat_ids = t1.cat_id 
GROUP BY t1.cat_id
```

### Result generated

[image: Result]

How can I get the information in table2 from the result(table) `GROUP_CONCAT(t2.content_id)` related to the `content_id`?

and Retrive those data from table2 Using PHP

Comment: so you want to concatenate the content instead of id?

Comment: @JW so id's will the replaced with the realted content

Comment: @JW how can i display that text on a page related to that content or id

Comment: then instead of `GROUP_CONCAT(t2.content_id)`, why not `GROUP_CONCAT(t2.title)`?

Comment: yea i did, it just displays the title

Comment: so what's the output you want?

Comment: how to get the data from table2 related to the group_concat result

Comment: @user1929491 Can you show desired result?

Comment: @Devart http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334632/retrive-data-from-table-with-has-group-concat-function here is the link for result plz check it

Comment: What is wrong with using two fields GROUP_CONCAT(t2.content_id) and GROUP_CONCAT(t2.title)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you got a one-to-many relationship here. Meaning one row in table1 can be related to 0-n rows in table2.

If you you group by the primary key of table1 you limit the result to one result row for each row in table one, by using `GROUP_CONCAT(table2_col)` you concatenate all matching rows of the table2_column with a separator which is comma by default.

Play with the following queries:

```
SELECT
     t1.*, 
     GROUP_CONCAT(t2.content_id) AS content_ids,
     GROUP_CONCAT(t2.title) AS content_titles
FROM 
    news_categories t1 
        LEFT JOIN news_content t2 ON t2.cat_ids = t1.cat_id 
GROUP BY t1.cat_id
```

Or

```
SELECT
     t1.*, 
     t2.*
FROM 
    news_categories t1 
        LEFT JOIN news_content t2 ON t2.cat_ids = t1.cat_id
```

I recommend to write out the columns you want, instead of using .*

**EDIT**

To separate the concatenated values in php have a look at [explode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php)

You fetch the data as usual e.g.

```
$result = mysqli_query( $query );
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
    print_r( $row );
}
```

Have a look at [this examples](http://www.php.net/manual/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: how can i get one to one for this tables can u suggest any query plz

Comment: Result(title n content) is  separated with a comma.. then how can i make this data to store in an array n print it using php