# Retrive data from table with has Group_concat function

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

This is Result of two table using GROUP_CONCAT() for columns content_ids and content_titles
and this data is separated with a ',' separator

[image: Result]

What i need is?

Using php the values must be stored in a array and should print at using a loop.

can anyone help me?
thanks.

Comment: What have you *tried* ? What you *get* ? What is *expected* ?

Comment: just use explode() on that field

Comment: yea i did it stores in a array like this array(array[0]=>0,[1]=>1)

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve your data usual way.
Then, after reading particular comma-separated field, use [explode()](http://php.net/explode) to get an array out of it.
That's all